# VS2010 wants to publish a non-existant file. How do I change it

Tags: visual-studio-2010, publishing

I screwed up my Web App solution in VS2010, Visual SVN wouldn't return me to a previous version so I checked out another copy in another directory.  Now I've made changes and it commits ok. However, Now VS2010 Publish is failing with:-

Error   4   Copying file assetmanager\assetmanager.asp to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\assetmanager\assetmanager.asp failed. Could not find file 'assetmanager\assetmanager.asp'.     0   0   AdminSite

I'm pretty certain there's never been an assetmanager\assetmanager.asp file. The site is .NET 4.0 VB.

I'm now totally stuck. Can anybody give me a hint as to how to correct this. I don't even know where it's getting this info from.

Cheers

Comment: If you look at the `.vbproj` file, is there a reference to the missing  `assetmanager.asp` file in there?

Comment: Never used Visual SVN but most SVN clients will have a cleanup option.  Have you tried this?  Also you have a better chance of getting an answer if you will accept answers that are valid....27% isn't very good.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean?  "Also you have a better chance of getting an answer if you will accept answers that are valid....27% isn't very good."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you seeing the file in the project? If so right click and tell it to remove the "ghost" file from the project.  Once you do that I would try and publish again.

If its not showing the project, you might be able to create a fake file with the same name (just put some text in there so the size isn't 0kb) and in the same location as the other asp files.   Make sure the "show hidden files is selected" and add it to the project and then promptly delete.  This would essentially fix the corruption of VS thinking the file exist.

Comment: That didn't work I'm afraid. I created an asp file in the right location, publish still failed. I removed the file, publish failed again. I even tried deleting Admin.Publish.xml but that didn't make any difference (it's now been recreated). I just don't know where it's getting it's information from. I'm assuming this is happening because the repository had some solution or project file in it.

Comment: Finally found it was due to a rogue directory in the root call assetmanager. Deleted it and all was well. However it was full of ghost files and not where the error message reported it. Bit wierd really, however, hope this little tale helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Found this problem and was able to solve it by:

1. Locate your .csproj file
2. Open it in Notepad and search for the offending file name
3. Delete the tag from your .csproj (make sure to remove an encapsulating dependencies), save and close
4. Reload your project, et voila!